# Is this somebody trying to exploit a vulnerability?

Tags: php, known-vulnerabilities, session-management

On our website, when an invalid PHP session ID is detected, it's logged and regenerated.

This **invalid** session has been logged:

`n040jl1nujch72tkrmr0uilnl1, s_vi=[CS]v1|2A19B9B4853135D2-60000109E00013F4[CE]`

**Is that somebody trying to exploit a vulnerability?**

This is the current way the ID is regenerated

```
// If it's invalid, generate a new ID.
$chars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,-";
srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
$i = 0;
$pass = '' ;
while ($i<=35){
    $num  = rand() % 33;
    $tmp  = substr($chars, $num, 1);
    $pass = $pass . $tmp;
    $i++;
}
session_id($pass);
```

But in the next few days, we're updating the codebase to use this is it needs regenerating.

```
session_id(uniqid());
```

Comment: how do you generate the session IDs ?

Comment: See my edit, I've added how we regenerate the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Do you write in logs which session IDs are generated?

Maybe 'good' user got this session id from your application, but then application 'forgot' about this? (because session expires or because application was restarted, server rebooted)

Simple guessing sessions id few times isn't very good way to hack site, maybe some tool like Splunk could greatly help you. (e.g. it can show that 99% of invalid session id error comes from requests from single IP - then it would really be suspicious).

Comment: No, we don't check against generated ID's, but looking at how we generate them, I don't think this could be generated by us. I think this is just a one off occurrence, we've only had this one invalid ID log.

Comment: maybe someone implemented the cookie jar in a wrong way?